i want to replicate old tables present on master machine also on to my slave machines how to do this?
My current replication is going on correctly in realtime now,
I want to replicate old tables present on master machine also on to my slave machines how to do this?
In my configuration file I have added replicate_db_table= databasename_tablename and then restarted MySQL.
It is not giving error and not replicating the old tables, and real-time both have stopped.

Did you try searching the web, reading the MySQL documents, or asking on https://dba.stackexchange.com/ ?
